# How to authenticate against Sharepoint Online with user credentials?

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to customize some lists for SharePoint Online and since I am new to the subject I do not know how to connect to the service.

When I use NAPA and from the cloud use the option "Edit in Visual Studio", I am prompted for credentials automatically when the project opens.
However, when I start from bottom-up, i.e. open a new project in Visual Studio, add all necessary dlls, this part of code throws an error (it is an authentication issue):

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://MYURL.sharepoint.com/n/"); 
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

I am using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

The error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in      Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I think I am missing part of the code which is responsible for authentication and which in case of NAPA app is hard-coded.

How can I authenticate to SharePoint Online? (it is enough if my code runs just once, it's not an app, I don't want to package it and publish)

I am guessing it has something to do with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.sharepoint.remote.authentication.aspx, but that's as far as I got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to authenticate against SharePoint Online using the managed CSOM

The CSOM for SharePoint 2013 introduces the [SharePointOnlineCredentials class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) that allows to perform an active authentication to SharePoint Online.

### Example

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the URL of the SharePoint Online site:");

        string webUrl = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your user name (format: username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com)");
        string userName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your password.");
        SecureString password = GetPasswordFromConsoleInput();

        using (var context = new ClientContext(webUrl))
        {
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName,password);
            context.Load(context.Web, w => w.Title);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("Your site title is: " + context.Web.Title);
        }
    }

    private static SecureString GetPasswordFromConsoleInput()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo info;

        //Get the user's password as a SecureString
        SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
        do
        {
            info = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(info.KeyChar);
            }
        }
        while (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        return securePassword;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will no longer work as SharePoint (along with most O365 apps/services) require modern authentication. You will need to create an Azure AD app and use the app ID and secret in order to connect rather than use user credentials.

Comment: @TylerH Any idea how to do this in code?